# Python/Pandas - creating new variable based on several variables and if/elif/else function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new variable that is conditional based on values from several other values. I'm writing here because I've tried writing this as a nested ifelse() statement in R, but it had too many nested ifelse's so it threw an error, and I think there should be an easier way to sort this out in Python.

I have a dataframe (called df) that looks roughly like this (although in reality it's much bigger with many more month/year variables) that I've read in as a pandas DataFrame:

```
   ID  Sept_2015  Oct_2015  Nov_2015  Dec_2015  Jan_2016  Feb_2016  Mar_2016  \
0   1          0         0         0         0         1         1         1   
1   2          0         0         0         0         0         0         0   
2   3          0         0         0         0         1         1         1   
3   4          0         0         0         0         0         0         0   
4   5          1         1         1         1         1         1         1   

   grad_time  
0        240  
1        218  
2        236  
3          0  
4        206
```

I'm trying to create a new variable that depends on values from all these variables, but values from "earlier" variables need to have precedent, so the if/elif/else condition would like something like this:

```
if df['Sept_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 236:
    return 236
elif df['Oct_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 237:
    return 237
elif df['Nov_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 238:
    return 238
elif df['Dec_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 239:
    return 239
elif df['Jan_2016'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 240:
    return 240
elif df['Feb_2016'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 241:
    return 241
elif df['Mar_2016'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 242:
    return 242
else:
    return 0
```

And based on this, I'd like it to return a new variable that looks like this:

```
   trisk
0    240
1      0
2    240
3      0
4    236
```

I've tried writing a function like this:

```
def test_func(df):
    """ Test Function for generating new value"""
    if df['Sept_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 236:
        return 236
    elif df['Oct_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 237:
        return 237
    ...
    else:
        return 0
```

and mapping it to the dataframe to create new variable like this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(map(test_func, df))
```

However, when I run it, I get the following TypeError

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-83-19b45bcda45a>", line 1, in <module>
     new_df = pd.DataFrame(map(new_func, test_df))

  File "<ipython-input-82-a2eb6f9d7a3a>", line 3, in new_func
     if df['Sept_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 236:

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

So I can see it's not wanting the column name here. But I've tried this a number of other ways and can't get it to work. Also, I understand this might not be the best way to write this (mapping the function) so I am open to new ways to attempt to solve the problem of generating the trisk variable. Thanks in advance and apologies if I haven't provided something.

Answer (score 3):

Without getting into streamlining your logic (which @piRSquared gets into): you can apply your `test_func` to the rows by issuing `.apply(test_func, axis=1)` to your dataframe.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO('''\
   ID  Sept_2015  Oct_2015  Nov_2015  Dec_2015  Jan_2016  Feb_2016  Mar_2016  grad_time  
0   1          0         0         0         0         1         1         1        240
1   2          0         0         0         0         0         0         0        218   
2   3          0         0         0         0         1         1         1        236
3   4          0         0         0         0         0         0         0          0
4   5          1         1         1         1         1         1         1        206
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

def test_func(df):
    """ Test Function for generating new value"""
    if df['Sept_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 236:
        return 236
    elif df['Oct_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 237:
        return 237
    elif df['Nov_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 238:
        return 238
    elif df['Dec_2015'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 239:
        return 239
    elif df['Jan_2016'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 240:
        return 240
    elif df['Feb_2016'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 241:
        return 241
    elif df['Mar_2016'] > 0 & df['grad_time'] <= 242:
        return 242
    else:
        return 0

trisk = df.apply(test_func, axis=1)
trick.name = 'trisk'
print(trisk)
```

Output:

```
0    240
1      0
2    240
3      0
4    236
Name: trisk, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 240],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 218],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 236],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   0],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 206]],
                  pd.Index(range(1, 6), name='ID'),
                  ['Sept_2015', 'Oct_2015', 'Nov_2015', 'Dec_2015',
                   'Jan_2016', 'Feb_2016', 'Mar_2016', 'grad_time'])
```

I used mostly numpy for this

```
a = np.array([236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242])
b = df.values[:, :-1]
g = df.values[:, -1][:, None] <= a

a[(b & g).argmax(1)] * (b & g).any(1)
```

Assigning it to new column

```
df['trisk'] = a[(b != 0).argmax(1)] * (b != 0).any(1)

df
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you want `[dates]` at the end of your setup.

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso that's what ensures I have the correct order to the columns and ensures I am giving "earlier" dates precedence.  If I messed it up, I'm happy to change it.  But I think that's right.

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso Agreed, I didn't spend a lot of time on it.  But I'll take your advice and fix it up.

Comment: You do get the OP's desired output, but there's something wrong with the logic: you don't use the OP's `grad_time` column!

Comment: Nicely done! One small improvement: you don't need `z` --- you can do `a[(b & g).argmax(1)] * (b & g).any(1)`.

Comment: Nice! I am shamelessly stealing this logic for my own implementation...